# How to update counter in BI Publisher for-each tag

Tags: bi-publisher

I have a counter variable: `<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘storeCounter’, 0)?>`

I put this counter into a for-each tag and hope that it will return the loop times:

```
<?for-each:G_1?>
    <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter') + 1)?>
```

Here is my report detail:
[image]

and data model xml:

```
<output rootName="DATA_DS" uniqueRowName="false">
<nodeList name="data-structure">
<dataStructure tagName="DATA_DS">
<group name="G_1" label="G_1" source="test">
<element name="TY_SOH_TOT" value="TY_SOH_TOT" label="TY_SOH_TOT" dataType="xsd:double" breakOrder="" fieldOrder="1"/>
<element name="LY_SOH_TOT" value="LY_SOH_TOT" label="LY_SOH_TOT" dataType="xsd:double" breakOrder="" fieldOrder="2"/>
<element name="LLY_SOH_TOT" value="LLY_SOH_TOT" label="LLY_SOH_TOT" dataType="xsd:double" breakOrder="" fieldOrder="3"/>
</group>
</dataStructure>
</nodeList>
</output>
```

But it just returns `1` as the result of the counter:

```
<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter')?>
```

So, how to make the counter updated correctly?

Comment: The syntax is correct. <?for-each:G_1?>
    <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter') + 1)?>
<?end for-each?>

<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter')?>
This works for me. If you can send the full xml and rtf to me, I can check it : alt.n4-8oko8ew8@yopmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your new xml, it seems you will have to loop through 'element' instead of 'group'. Looping through 'group' will give you 0.

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter', 0)?>
<?for-each: element?> 
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter') + 1)?> 
<?end for-each?> 
<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter')?>
```

Will give you 3.

Comment: Thank you, with your help I have seen the root cause :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you closed the for loop ?

```
<?for-each:G_1?>
    <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter') + 1)?>
<?end for-each?>

<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter')?>
```

Prints the count.

If you just need the count, you can use `<?count(G_1)?>`, gives the count without looping

Comment: Yes, I have closed the loop with `<?end for-each?>` tag. Beside the counter I also need some calculation in the loop. I have edited my question for more details about my report. Please, review it.

Comment: Could you post the xml ?

Comment: I have uploaded xml in the question. Is it the xml that you mention?